# Why is my dconf setting suddenly non-writable?

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon, screensaver, dconf

I'm trying to change my screensaver settings in `Cinnamon 2.6.13` on `Ubuntu 14.04 trusty`.

When the system image was fresh, I was able to change the setting `/org/cinnamon/desktop/screensaver/ask-for-away-message` to whatever I wanted.  Now, however, the option seems to be "locked" at false, and using `dconf write` (even with `sudo`) gives the following output:

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/screensaver/ask-for-away-message true
error: The operation attempted to modify one or more non-writable keys
```

The only thing I can think of that could have caused this was when I tried a new screensaver a few weeks ago.  I hated it and changed it back to default, but since then I haven't been able to change the setting of ask-for-away-message, and I really want it to true again...

Why is the setting now "non-writable"?

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks, I just checked that directory but it doesn't seem to exist, so it seems that it isn't.

Comment: Can you create a new user to check, if the problem is in the system or in your /home?

Comment: @Bahamut Unfortunately, I can not create a new user to check.

Comment: Long shot.  Logout and stop Xorg.  Rename following folder.  $HOME/.gconf $HOME/..gconfd $HOME/.dbus $HOME/.config/dconf. But this will reset all your approaches.

Comment: Please check the *directory* permissions in `$HOME/.config/*`. I had that a couple of times as well. Not sure what caused it, but one of the directories (`dconf/`?) suddenly was owned by `root`. After a `sudo chown <myUser>:<myGroup>` <directory>` things where back to normal. Generally spoken, a `sudo chown -R <myUser>:<myGroup> $HOME/.config` should not cause any harm, and fix this very issue as well.

Comment: @Izzy I just tried that, but still no luck.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez tried the "global hammer" `chown`ing recursively? OK, then it must be something different in your case. Just to make sure: can you check if anything in there is set to read-only? Though, what irritates me is the "non-writable **key**" part of your error message. // For context: [this is the code](https://github.com/GNOME/dconf/blob/master/engine/dconf-engine.c#L1118) where it throws that error – maybe it helps some dev to get a clue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but I found the solution to a very similar problem I was having.

Look in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/screensaver` and see if your key is listed. Anything listed in this file is locked, and cannot be changed at all.

Also check `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-screensaver`, as that file forces global settings, which might also be affecting it.

More info can be found at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1201153.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some program set a lock on the according key. I found this in the Gnome developer documentation, probably works also with your system as it uses dconf.

> ## Locks
>
> System databases can contain 'locks' for keys. If a lock for a particular key or subpath is installed into a database then no database listed above that one in the profile will be able to modify any of the affected settings. This can be used to enforce mandatory settings.
>
> To add locks to a database, place text files in the /etc/dconf/db/database.d/locks directory, where database is the name of a system database, as specified in the profile. The files contain list of keys to lock, on per line. Lines starting with a # are ignored. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> # prevent changes to the company wallpaper
> /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
> ```
>
> After changing locks, the database needs to be updated with the dconf(1) tool.

Copied from https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas:

1. You are trying to write a **VALUE** of a wrong type; e.g. write a *string* into an *integer* **KEY**
2. Try to reset that **KEY**, prior to write in it

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty, but neither of these helped fix the problem.